# how to make edges of a line fade out?

Tags: css

This bit of css will center a 1 pixel tall bar in its container.  I change its width to indicate progress of something loading.

```
#centered_bar {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

How would I make the left and right edge of this element 'fade' (so, when zoomed in, the edge would look like the bottom line-end in this picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be something similar to a gradient fill and would be subject to some browser compatibility issues so your best best is using a JavaScript library like CSS3Pie, and animate the appropriate property with jQuery or something similar.

I would start here: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#gradients

Good luck!